# typescript: Property 'label' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

How can fix this error :

Property 'label' does not exist on type 'never'

```
  <Picker
        dropdownIconColor='black'
        mode="dropdown">
        {stateList.map(option => <Picker.Item label={option.label} key={option.key} value={option.value} />)}
      </Picker>
```

Comment: Where is `stateList` declared? What type does it have?

Comment: `const [stateList, setStateList] = useState([]);`

Comment: Typescript thinks it's an Array<never>, you need to type it or use type Array<any> if you're lazy

Comment: how i should write it ? can u show me the right way to do ?

Comment: `const [stateList, setStateList] = useState<Array<any>>([])` basically

Comment: please try once by using hardcode values `const [stateList, setStateList] = useState([{label:"asd",key:0,value:"asd"}]);`

Answer (score 0):

The useState hook is used as follows in Typescript:

```
//react javascript
const [wearablesList, setWearablesList] = useState([]);

//react typescript
interface Provider {
  connected: boolean;
  type: string;
}
const [wearablesList, setWearablesList] = useState<Provider[]>([]);
```